Knockoff R package removing ALL variables based on LASSO, Why?
I am simulating a data set from a linear regression model and selecting the variables using LASSO (glmnet). The selection works relatively well with lambda.1se and lambda.min, but it contains some false positives, as usual with LASSO. The results are reproduced in the R code below.
library(knockoff)
library(glmnet)

# Simulate data
set.seed(2024)
p <- 100  # Number of features
n <- 80   # Number of samples
k <- 15   # Number of truly relevant features

# Generate data with some features correlated
mu <- rep(0, p)
Sigma <- diag(p)
X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), n)
nonzero <- sample(p, k)
beta <- 3.5 * (1:p %in% nonzero)
y <- X %*% beta + rnorm(n)
which(beta>0)


# Define response variable (assuming it's stored in 'y')
model <- cv.glmnet(X, y, alpha = 1)

# Explore model coefficients and other properties using:
coef(model, s = 'lambda.min')  
coef(model, s = 'lambda.1se')

cbind(beta, coef(model, s = 'lambda.min')[-1])
cbind(beta, coef(model, s = 'lambda.1se')[-1])

So, I thought of creating a knockoff matrix (https://web.stanford.edu/group/candes/knockoffs/) to check if this would reduce the false positives (FDR), but it ends up removing all variables! See the code below. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.
# Run knockoff filter
result <- knockoff.filter(X, y)

# Knockoff matrix is stored in result$Xk
# After running knockoff.filter (from previous example)
knockoff_matrix <- result$Xk

# Define response variable (assuming it's stored in 'y')
modelk <- cv.glmnet(knockoff_matrix, y, alpha = 1)

# Explore model coefficients and other properties using:
coef(modelk, s = 'lambda.min')  
coef(modelk, s = 'lambda.1se')


You're using only the knockoff variables (and none of your real variables)! See the example under the function you are calling "knockoff.filter" in the docs https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knockoff/knockoff.pdf for proper usage. (Basically you can stop after "result <- ...").

@JohnMadden I get it know, my analysis was all messed up. I could accept your comment as an answer if you post it as such.

@JohnMadden If you don't mind me asking, if I wanted to use the knockoff matrix to run another LASSO, which variable or matrix do I need to extract from that object? Or do I need to use another matrix? Or does my question make any sense?

I'm not 100% sure exactly what the equivalent procedure is, but it's going to involve concatenating the knockoff variables with the original variables (e.g. using cbind). PS: the source code is pure R and pretty easy to read.
